# Finding birth and death dates for brother who was born and died in Bucharest, Romania during 1930s?

Tags: 20th-century, vital-records, romania

I am looking for precise dates of birth and death for my brother.

All that I know is that he was born in Bucharest, Romania between 1933 to 1935 and died in 1935 in the same location. So was he was aged 0-2.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE, I re-stated your question to refine what you are asking. If there are any details you can add as far as specific locations, ethnicity, deceased parents that full within the [community guidelines](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help). Please click on the edit button and add them.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Regrettably I have had to remove your brother's name from this question because we have to adhere to our our [privacy policy related to people born less than 100 years](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Hopefully we can help you with possible places to find the information, and if for example, you can locate a link to his death record to post, then we will be able to restore his name to help search for his birth record.

Comment: We have now had a number of [questions asked here about how to find Romanian ancestors](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romania) and I thought I had found an answer that might be particularly useful to you in http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/5490 but it seems to only cover people born there more than 100 years ago.

Comment: Butnaru, i have listened histories about you, i can say legends, that we have some relatives in US, but the communist party i see changed a bit our names, now you see im Botnaru, you are still Butnaru, im not sure that legends is about you, but my granmother use tot tell, that in Florida there is our man. Have a very nice day, and best wishes from Romania and Moldova.

Answer (score 2):

Church records (those still in the local churches, not those in archives) would be the good option to pursue. You would have to know the denomination, and probably the parish, before writing or visiting. Perhaps you have your own baptismal papers that would provide clues to that information.

Answer (score 2):

As the brother of the person looked for, you are entitled to apply with official authorities for his birth and death records. If you know the years and place, a search can be made, although it could take some time.

There are two ways to apply from abroad:

1. Through www.econsulat.ro, which is free, but takes literally months / years. This platform is just to apply and register. Once you get the pre-approval, you must go to the nearest Romanian consulate to sign the application as well; or
2. Go through a specialist like www.romaniandocuments.net.

The records are not digitized in any way, and there is no public database.