# Where to find Birth and Death Records for Bucharest, Romania?

Tags: vital-records, romania

My husband's family came from Bucharest. Specifically his mother was born in Sibiu.  I have been able to piece together names and relations of several grand and great grandparents from word of mouth and some fortunate pictures they had of the cemetery in Sibiu.  I cannot however find any records of birth's and death's for any of them.

Are there sites or organizations that hold records for Romania?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE?  As a new user be sure to take the 2-minute [Tour].  Would you be able to **edit** your question using the button beneath it to add the period for which you are seeking these records.  Also, make sure you review our [Help/on-topic] advice on how to ask questions concerning anyone born within the last 100 years to avoid raising any privacy issues.  As it stands your question is fine.

Comment: Also be sure to review earlier Q&As here that are tagged [tag:romania] because both Bucharest and Sibiu have been mentioned before.  In particular, depending on the era, your question may be a duplicate of http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8043/finding-birth-and-death-dates-for-brother-who-was-born-and-died-in-bucharest-ro.

Answer (score 2):

Vital Records in Romania are kept by two types of institutions:

1. Town halls, for records less than 100 years old;
2. The National Archives, as well as sometimes Churches, for records older than 100 years old.

The cutoff date is not set in stone. Older and newer records can be found in both places.

Romanian vital records are considered private information. Therefore, only your husband can apply for them, and must do so through legal, rather than historical / genealogical channels. To do so, he can ask the Romanian Consulate, including by internet on www.econsulat.ro, which is free but takes years (literally), particularly for purely genealogical purposes. Or he can go through a specialist like www.romaniandocuments.net.