# Finding 1904 Birth Record from Constanta, Romania?

Tags: birth-records, 1900s-decade, romania

My mother's mother was born at Constanta, Romania, at 1904 and after a time she immigrated to Istanbul,Turkey. She died at 1980 at Istanbul.

I want to find her birth records at Romania, where l must apply for finding her birth papers?

Comment: See https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/13077/6485