# Looking for ancestor in or around Râvâsel, Sibiu, Romania?

Tags: romania

I have some limited information about a great-grandfather.

So far, this is the information that I have:

- Johann Löprich
- Born around 1868
- Married to 18 April 1892 to Anna Müller in Rafael, Sibiu, (Hermannstadt) Romania
- Father - Johann Löprich
- Mother - Maria Löprich
- Died around 1929 in Canton, Ohio, USA

How do I find more information about Johann in order to find other relatives either in Romania or who may have immigrated to Germany or Austria after the war?

Comment: This is too broad to be a good fit for this site -- can you narrow it down to a single question? Perhaps asking how you can locate a birth record?

Comment: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/finding-romanian-ancestors-from-sibiu-gu%c8%99teri%c8%9ba and https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9172/where-to-find-birth-and-death-records-for-bucharest-romania may be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Löprich is a common Transylvania Saxon surname and the German name for Râvâsel is Rosch. There are many resources for Transyvania Saxon research besides the official Romanian records.

**Historical records**

While Rosch was a relatively small village, Ancestry.com does include 1885-1895 baptism, marriage and burial records of the Lutheran church in Rosch in [Romania, Vital Records from Selected Regions, 1607-1914](https://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=5412)

There is a [project](https://vgss.de/genealogie/) based in Germany to extract records from various sources but there doesn't seem to be anyone concentrating on Rosch.

**Contemporary Contacts**

- Join one of the mailing lists or message boards for Transylvanian Saxons
- Visit [Siebenbürgische Zeitung Online](https://www.siebenbuerger.de/zeitung/) for news and [siebenbuerger.de Rosch](https://www.siebenbuerger.de/ortschaften/rosch/) for photos, contacts, etc. specific to Rosch.